# Use of AngularJS with ASPX page in .net 4.0/4.5 versions

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

How can we use AngularJS in web form (aspx page) in .net 4.0/4.5 versions.
ng-app, ng-controller etc.. are not working in the page . What is the main reason that we can't use AngularJS there. Please suggest some possible answers.

Comment: What have you tried ? Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.try to  Search and research and try writing some code. 
If you then have trouble, you can come back here and ask a proper question, providing [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

this is a perfect guide for angular 2, it is not what you need but it might help you figuring it out.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to figure out exactly what is the problem from your question. Most likely you don't load angular correctly. But one thing I can say for certain:

There is nothing preventing Angular 1 from working with Web Forms.

I have done it 
myself and all works. Just make sure you add proper scripts and stuff in your master page.